# Making a timer on delay and off delay without microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, 555, robotics

I am new and want to make a compact circuit without a microcontroller. The idea is when you push the button/switch, it will delay the timer for at least 6 hours. After that, it will activate the motor for 20 seconds and loop forever. I am thinking of using a 555 timer with a 10000uF capacitor here, but it fails miserably. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Rather make low freq. oscillator (about 1hz) and divide the clock with counter like 4020 (14bit).

Comment: How accurate does the delay need to be?  Do you want 6h +/- 5 ms or 6h +/- 5%?

Comment: an 8 pin microcontroller would allow the circuit to be much smaller

Comment: These parts combine oscillators with dividers, very long delays are possible. There are several variations, with different logic polarities. LTC6995IS6

Answer (score 2):

Analog timers of 6 hours are difficult because things like leakage (in this case, capacitor leakage) will get you even if you buy special low-leakage electrolytics.

You can make a 555 oscillator divide that down by a number like 1024 or 2048 and then the 555 frequency only has to be 10 or 20 seconds. You can also calibrate the timer, if required, without waiting 6 hours by using a lower division ratio. Something like a CD4020, as suggested above, or a 74HC4040 (5V-ish supply). You can trigger a second 555 from the falling edge of the divider to give you the 20 seconds.

If you care about the time to the first 20 second interval (the 6 hours) you need to find a way to reset the counter reliably (on the plus side, the longer time you get out of the 555 first cycle after power-up no longer matters). There are plenty of good ways to do that on a 5V or 3.3V circuit, less so for a 12V circuit.

This is how it could have been (and probably would have been) done 50 years ago. Of course today it would be much simpler circuitry-wise and would yield more stable and accurate times using a microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, practical circuits with time constants this large won't be easy, and not precise, *at all*!

Alongside part variations that become very significant for capabilities this size, suddenly a lot of other effects, like nonlinear charge curves and leakage currents start to become relevant. Sorry: your preference, the 555, is the wrong tool for the job! Hour-long delays are not in it.

This sounds like a task for an oscillator, feeding a counter, feeding a finite state machine, feeding your output.

Now, I think you can piece together mentally what a regularly clocked logic circuit with a configurable state machine is: it's the precursor to a *processor*. Now, it's significantly simpler to a processor on paper, but by a very large margin, I'd say your relatively complex logic with large delays would be easier to implement as software running on a microcontroller than as discrete logic.

Don't let that stop you, though! If you have time to tinker, you can build a Pierce oscillator with but an inverter gate and a (e.g. quartz) resonator. Counter chips are available, and you'll easily find a suitable factorization of the number of clock cycles it takes, so that you can cascade counters to achieve that (hint: clock halvers are easy, maybe factor out a power of 2 first!).

Your finite state machine is really simple, wait 6 hrs with output of, wait 20s with output on. You'll find that completely implementable with muxes.

Have fun! This will look s bit daunting at first, but keep your problem cleanly divided into testable parts, and you will learn a lot!